# WireGuard VPN: how safe is it for production in its current state?

Tags: vpn, audit, protocols, risk-analysis, wireguard

In our project we had to build a VPN to get through to computers residing behind NAT. I never did it before. While looking for suitable software I came across [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com) which claimed to be very simple.

After some [reading](https://linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/set-up-wireguard-vpn-on-ubuntu/) I indeed was able to setup a server with 8 lines long config file and a client (that was behind NAT) with 9 lines long config.

The link worked perfectly in both directions. After that for obvious reasons I don't want to touch any alternatives. WG is on its way to the mainstream Linux kernel, but it is not there yet.

[The protocol](https://www.wireguard.com/protocol/) was [formally verified](https://www.wireguard.com/formal-verification/) and [technical whitepaper](https://www.wireguard.com/papers/wireguard.pdf) exists as well. However the [website claims](https://www.wireguard.com/#about-the-project) WireGuard shouldn't be "relied on".

How risky is it, from information security point of view, to use WG in production in its current state? What are potential troubles?

**Update:** As of 2020 WireGuard is inside mainstream Linux kernel, so quite production ready.

Comment: I imagine the troubles are primarily related to the quality of the code (which will be better scrutinized when it is accepted upstream). The protocol itself seems solid and the choice of algorithms is very sane. I only wish they used a hybrid handshake (PQC), but according to the main dev, he's worried that none of the options have been sufficiently vetted yet.

Comment: Also, there's an official channel on Freenode, where you may get more authoritative answers.

Comment: Just to add to @user28177 there is now official open source windows client - see https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-windows Regarding current security status there are some ongoing projects - see https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2018/project/He-Xu-Xu-WireGuard.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm actually excited about WireGuard too. There is already [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireguard.android), [macOS](https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2018-May/002854.html), [Windows](https://tunsafe.com/)(third party - closed source) and [OpenBSD](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-ports&m=152712417729497&w=2) clients, showing that the project have a solid future ahead. Tight integration with `ip-link` also seems a bonus and configuration is a no-brainer.

But if you take a look at the homepage, specially the "[About Project](https://www.wireguard.com/#work-in-progress)" section, you will see a warning about using it on production:

> ### About The Project
>
> #### Work in Progress
>
> WireGuard is not yet complete. You should not rely on this code. It
> has not undergone proper degrees of security auditing and the protocol
> is still subject to change. We're working toward a stable 1.0 release,
> but that time has not yet come. There are experimental snapshots
> tagged with "0.0.YYYYMMDD", but these should not be considered real
> releases and they may contain security vulnerabilities (which would
> not be eligible for CVEs, since this is pre-release snapshot
> software). If you are packaging WireGuard, you must keep up to date
> with the snapshots.
>
> However, if you're interested in helping out, we could really use your
> help and we readily welcome any form of feedback and review. There's
> currently quite a bit of work to do on the project todo list, and the
> more folks testing this out, the better.

Basically this project could have CVEs and it is under heavy development and constant change. Maybe it's not suitable to your organization. Also, no opensource Windows client, and a client that relies on tun/tap devices kludge.

Comment: The tunsafe project is not official, closed-source and relies on the tuntap driver from the openvpn project. I would be cautious with this implemention and wait for an (official,) auditable opensource implementation if you plan to use it on Windows.

Comment: That's right. The Windows client is developed by a third party. Another reason to AVOID implementing WireGuard in production...